# Using OpenGL glutDisplayFunc within class

Tags: c++, opengl, class, compiler-errors

I've created a C++ class (`myPixmap`) to encapsulate the work performed by the OpenGL GLUT toolkit.  The `display()` member function of the class contains most of the code required to set up GLUT.

```
void myPixmap::display()
{
    // open an OpenGL window if it hasn't already been opened
    if (!openedWindow)
    {
        // command-line arguments to appease glut
        char *argv[] = {"myPixmap"};
        int argc = 1;
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
        glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
        glutInitWindowPosition(30, 30);
        glutCreateWindow("Experiment");
        glutDisplayFunc(draw);
        glClearColor(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 0.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glutMainLoop();

        openedWindow = true;
    }  
}
```

The display function passed to `glutDisplayFunc()` is another member function of the class:

```
void myPixmap::draw(void)
{
    glDrawPixels( m,n,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel );
}
```

However, gcc 4.2.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.4 refuses to compile this code, claiming that:

`argument of type 'void (myPixmap::)()' does not match 'void (*)()'`

Is there a way to use the GLUT toolkit inside a member function of a class, or must I call all GLUT functions within the `main` function of the program?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem is that a pointer to an instance bound member function has to include the `this` pointer.  OpenGL is a C API, and knows nothing about `this` pointers.  You'll have to use a static member function (which doesn't require an instance, and thus no `this`), and set some static data members (to access the instance) in order to use `glutDisplayFunc`.

```
class myPixmap
{
private:
  static myPixmap* currentInstance;

  static void drawCallback()
  {
    currentInstance->draw();
  }

  void setupDrawCallback()
  {
    currentInstance = this;
    ::glutDisplayFunc(myPixmap::drawCallback);
  }
};
```

You may also have problems with C linkage vs C++ linkage, in which case you'll have to play around with `extern "C"`.  If so, you might have to use a global function, rather than a static member function as your callback, and have *that* call `myPixmap::draw`.  Something like:

```
class myPixmap
{
public:
  void draw();

private:
  void setupDrawCallback();
};

myPixmap* g_CurrentInstance;

extern "C"
void drawCallback()
{
  g_CurrentInstance->draw();
}

void myPixmap::setupDrawCallback();
{
  ::g_CurrentInstance = this;
  ::glutDisplayFunc(::drawCallback);
}
```

With all of this, try to make as few changes as possible, since this is really kind of a kludge to deal w/ OpenGL being a C API.

If you want multiple instances (I don't think most people using GLUT make multiple instances, but maybe you are), you'll have to figure out a solution using a std::map to retrieve the instance:

```
static std::map<int, myPixmap> instanceMap;
```

Where you'd get the `int` to resolve *which* instance, I am not sure :)

FYI, you should define functions that take no parameters this way:

```
void some_function() { }
```

not

```
void some_function(void) { }
```

Comment: Thanks Merlyn; this is an excellent solution.  I found that in my case, I had problems with C linkage vs C++ linkage, so I had to use a global function as shown in your second block of example code.  Finally I was able to compile the program. I don't require multiple instances, so this is not an issue for me yet.

Answer (score 4):

Please check this tutorial, I think this is what you are looking for:
http://paulsolt.com/2010/08/glut-object-oriented-framework-on-github/

Comment: Thanks; this is an interesting tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Merlyn solution didnt work for me, so I made a little modification by bringing currentInstance outside of class and it worked:

```
Class myPixmap;
static myPixmap* currentInstance;
Class myPixmap {
...
}
```

Comment: All the other options didn't work for me, but this ran perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble in understanding the correct answer from Merlyn, so here it is the simplified version:

In **myPixmap.h**, change display function to **static** member function. Should work.

```
class myPixmap
{
  //...
  static void display();
  //...
};
```