# Using GLUT in an Object Oriented Program

Tags: c++, opengl, object, linker, glut

I'm setting up a simulator in C++ for a simple problem domain. The underlying mechanics are written in one class MountainCar.cpp, which stores as a member a reference to a GUI that's implemented in another class called MCViewer.cpp. I've had decent exposure to GLUT, so I figured instead of fumbling around with alternatives, I could just create what's supposed to be a simple GUI using GLUT. The problem is that I might have more than one simulation running at a time, and I want every instance to have its own GUI. This may be common knowledge, but GLUT is a C API and certain calls that I need like glutDisplayFunc and glutReshapeFunc require pointers to C functions as arguments. Meanwhile I need the behavior of the functions being passed to depend on some arbitrary MCViewer object instance.

I found a useful [thread here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589422/using-opengl-glutdisplayfunc-within-class), which suggested creating and instead passing global callback functions, while implementing the corresponding callee functions inside the MCViewer class. Since the callback functions are global but intend to operate on some specified object instance, another global variable that stores a reference to some current MCViewer object is needed.

The resulting header:

```
#ifndef MCVIEWER_H__
#define MCVIEWER_H__

#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>

class MCViewer {
    //MCViewer declarations, implementation specified in corresponding .cpp
};

extern MCViewer *currRef;

extern "C" {    
    static void displayFcnCB(void) {
        currRef->displayFcn();
    }

    static void winReshapeFcnCB(GLint newWidth, GLint newHeight) {
        currRef->winReshapeFcn(newWidth, newHeight);
    }

    static void keyboardActionCB(GLubyte key, GLint xMouse, GLint yMouse) {
        currRef->keyboardAction(key, xMouse, yMouse);
    }
}

#endif //MCVIEWER_H__
```

The problem stems from including this file in both the MCViewer.cpp AND MountainCar.h files. Recall a MountainCar object, by my design, is supposed to store a reference to its assigned GUI. Before I made the global functions static, and marked the global variable currRef extern, I was originally getting "duplicate" errors during linking. Now I get some bizarre error that says currRef is being referenced from both MCViewer.o and MountainCar.o.

Comment: Do you insist on using glut? There are some alternatives that are better suited to object orientation. Also there is `qglviewer` for `Qt` integration.

Comment: My only insistance stems from familiarity, and the hour or so I spent earlier implementing it already in GLUT. I'll look into QT for the time being. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Qt would better suit you if you're just doing UI stuff, and no raw drawing?

http://qt.nokia.com/

Comment: There is some raw drawing involved. In fact it's mostly a graphic interface, with no user interactivity. Basically all I need is to draw a cosine curve to represent a hill, and then a rectangle to represent a car trying to get out of it. But I will look into QT for the time being! Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

> but OpenGL is a C API and certain calls that I need like glutDisplayFunc and glutReshapeFunc require pointers to C functions as arguments

So? GLUT is not part of OpenGL, it's just some 3rd party framework. You can, and in fact should not use GLUT for anything complex.

Comment: That's a good point. I wasn't completely conscious of what I was describing, so I apologize. My problem stems from the GLUT functions. I use some GL methods in my implementation, but you're right it's the GLUT stuff that's getting in my way. Based on what I have, do you know of any way around the linking problems I'm facing?

Comment: @bchillerr: I suggest not using GLUT. If you want a C++ OOP based framework for OpenGL, have a look at SFML http://www.sfml-dev.org/ – personally I'm not a huge fan of C++, I rather prefer using C (you can do OOP with C as well, it requires more elbow grease, but gives you greater freedom), but that's just a personal opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get away with creating a global map between window identifiers and GUI objects, and using `glutGetWindow` to get the current window id in the global display or reshape function.

Answer (score 0):

> I could just create what's supposed to be a simple GUI using GLUT.

If you want GUI, then I suggest to use something else. Qt initializes OpenGL, and provides powerful framework for cross-platform development. There's really no good reason (I could think of) to use GLUT for multi-window applications.

```
extern MCViewer *currRef;

extern "C" {    
    static void displayFcnCB(void) {
        currRef->displayFcn();
    }
```

You'll avoid a lot of trouble if you'll stop trying to do everything within header.

> Before I made the global functions static, and marked the global variable currRef extern, I was originally getting "duplicate" errors during linking.

static keyword for non-member function means that function is visible within one *.cpp file, and it is not visible to linker. Since you include **static function that is located outside of any class** into header, you're likely to get problems. Remove static keyword, put function body into *.cpp file, and forward declaration into header. Or keep it static and put it into class. Or keep it static non-member function, but remove any mention of that function from headers. Also, you do not need to use `extern "C"`.

> another global variable that stores a reference to some current MCViewer object is needed.

there's `glutGetCurrentWindow` function that is supposed to return ID of current window. Instead of trying to pass function parameters via global variables, use map (`std::map` or similar) - that'll map window IDs to "viewer" class pointers. Trying to pass function parameters via global variables is an **EXTREMELY** bad programming habit that will make your code unmaintainable.

However, at this point, dropping GLUT and using different GUI framework might be a better idea.