# What does the signature of a method have to be to work with glutDisplayFunc()?

Tags: c++, opengl, function-pointers, glut, freeglut

So, I am initially trying to do some basic OpenGL (freeglut) stuff in C++, but I've hit a snag. I am getting the following error:

```
.../TextureMapper.cpp: In member function 'void TextureMapper::run()':
.../TextureMapper.cpp:67:28: error: cannot convert 'TextureMapper::display' from type 'void* (TextureMapper::)()' to type 'void (*)()'  
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
                              ^
```

I think that I need `display` to be a function pointer (or whatever it is called, I'm not terribly familiar with that concept). However, I am doing it wrong. I've never used a function pointer before, and unfortunately the error message means nothing to me, and I can't understand the documentation that I have read. I'm a Java programmer, so it's all very foreign to me.

Here is the declaration for the member function in `TextureMapper.h`:

```
void* display(void);
```

And the instantiation (can't remember what this is called either) in `TextureMapper.cpp`:

```
void* TextureMapper::display(void)
{
    ...
}
```

I noticed that CLion was giving me a warning about this type, but I also tried this first:

```
void display();
```

But it gave a similar error.

Here is where I am trying to call `glutDisplayFunc`:

```
void TextureMapper::run()
{
    /* Run GL */
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: `TextureMapper` is a class. `display` and `run` are member functions inside of it.

Comment: Note that `void display();` has the correct signature. You want a function without return value (i.e. a `void(*)()` function pointer) but `void* display();` would return a `void*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glutDisplayFunc` expects a C function pointer. This pointer cannot come from a non static member function, because, in C++, member functions are mangled.

So, to be able to make this work, one solution is to define your `TextureMapper::Display` as a static member function.

So, try something like this:

```
class TextureMapper
{
public:
    static void display(void);
    ....
};
```

and in texturemapper.cpp

```
void TextureMapper::display(void) { \* implementation here *\}
```

Comment: Pointed me in the right direction. I also needed to use variables stored in `TextureMapper` to know what to draw, so I had to consult the linked duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589422/using-opengl-glutdisplayfunc-within-class